# Symfony2 - How to perform an external Request

Tags: php, http, symfony

Using Symfony2, I need to access an external API based on HTTPS.

How can I call an external URI and manage the response to "play" with it. For example, to render a success or a failure message?

I am thinking in something like (note that performRequest is a completely invented method):

```
$response = $this -> performRequest("www.someapi.com?param1=A&param2=B");

if ($response -> getError() == 0){
    // Do something good
}else{
    // Do something too bad
}
```

I have been reading about Buzz and other clients. But I guess that Symfony2 should be able to do it by its own.

Comment: What kind of request? Just HTTP GET?

Comment: Any GET or POST would be good to know ;)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I'd suggest using CURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.someapi.com?param1=A&param2=B');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json')); // Assuming you're requesting JSON
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

// If using JSON...
$data = json_decode($response);
```

**Note:** The php on your web server must have the `php5-curl` library installed.

Assuming the API request is returning JSON data, [this page](http://themekraft.com/getting-json-data-with-php-curl/) may be useful.

This doesn't use any code that is specific to Symfony2. There may well be a bundle that can simplify this process for you, but if there is I don't know about it.

Comment: Just want to note that the example contains an erroneous use of a `Content-Type` header. When used in a request, it indicates the type of the body (which isn't used in your example). To indicate what type you would like the server to return, you would use an `Accept` header, e.g. `Accept: application/json` header

Answer (score 27):

Symfony doesn't have a built-in service for this, but this is a perfect opportunity to create your own, using the dependency injection framework. What you can do here is write a service to manage the external call. Let's call the service "http".

First, write a class with a `performRequest()` method:

```
namespace MyBundle\Service;

class Http
{    
    public function performRequest($siteUrl)
    {
        // Code to make the external request goes here
        // ...probably using cUrl
    }
}
```

Register it as a service in `app/config/config.yml`:

```
services:
    http:
        class: MyBundle\Service\Http
```

Now your controller has access to a service called "http". Symfony manages a single instance of this class in the "container", and you can access it via `$this->get("http")`:

```
class MyController
{
    $response = $this->get("http")->performRequest("www.something.com");

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Best client that I know is: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/

There is already bundle that integrates it into Symfony2 project: 
https://github.com/8p/GuzzleBundle

```
$client   = $this->get('guzzle.client');

// send an asynchronous request.
$request = $client->createRequest('GET', 'http://httpbin.org', ['future' => true]);
// callback
$client->send($request)->then(function ($response) {
    echo 'I completed! ' . $response;
});

// optional parameters
$response = $client->get('http://httpbin.org/get', [
    'headers' => ['X-Foo-Header' => 'value'],
    'query'   => ['foo' => 'bar']
]);
$code = $response->getStatusCode();
$body = $response->getBody();

// json response
$response = $client->get('http://httpbin.org/get');
$json = $response->json();

// extra methods
$response = $client->delete('http://httpbin.org/delete');
$response = $client->head('http://httpbin.org/get');
$response = $client->options('http://httpbin.org/get');
$response = $client->patch('http://httpbin.org/patch');
$response = $client->post('http://httpbin.org/post');
$response = $client->put('http://httpbin.org/put');
```

More info can be found on: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Just note that Guzzle require PHP >= 5.5.0, which is a bit more recent that the symfony requirements (v5.3.3) :)

Comment: From GuzzleBundle github page: 
Requirements PHP 5.4 or above but now Guzzle lib require PHP >= 5.5.0. I think this has changed since my answer.

Comment: Yeah, but this does not seem up-to-date, I just proposed a pull-request to correct it on GuzzleBundle repository. I think the author of both Guzzle and GuzzleBundle will finally come with the answer :)
+1 anyway, I did not know this excellent library, thanks for talking about it!

Comment: No problem. I've checked it again and latest version of GuzzleBundle is using Guzzle 5.3 which requires PHP 5.4: http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/5.3/overview.html#requirements . Guzzle 6.0 requires PHP 5.5.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed it just after writing the comment actually. Author is however looking if Guzzle v6 can be supported by GuzzleBundle. So it might change soon, but I talked a bit too fast at the moment. Sorry for the disturbs !

Answer (score 10):

https://github.com/sensio/SensioBuzzBundle seems to be what you are looking for.

It implements the Kris Wallsmith buzz library to perform HTTP requests.

I'll let you read the doc on the github page, usage is pretty basic:

```
$buzz = $this->container->get('buzz');

$response = $buzz->get('http://google.com');

echo $response->getContent();
```

Answer (score 3):

Symfony does not have its own rest client, but as you already mentioned there are a couple of bundles. This one is my prefered one:

https://github.com/CircleOfNice/CiRestClientBundle

```
$restClient = $this->container->get('ci.restclient');

$restClient->get('http://www.someUrl.com');
$restClient->post('http://www.someUrl.com', 'somePayload');
$restClient->put('http://www.someUrl.com', 'somePayload');
$restClient->delete('http://www.someUrl.com');
$restClient->patch('http://www.someUrl.com', 'somePayload');

$restClient->head('http://www.someUrl.com');
$restClient->options('http://www.someUrl.com', 'somePayload');
$restClient->trace('http://www.someUrl.com');
$restClient->connect('http://www.someUrl.com');
```

You send the request via

```
$response = $restclient->get($url);
```

and get a Symfony response object.
Then you can get the status code via

```
$httpCode = $response-> getStatusCode();
```

Your code would look like:

```
$restClient = $this->container->get('ci.restclient');
if ($restClient->get('http://www.yourUrl.com')->getStatusCode !== 200) {
    // no error
} else {
    // error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [HttpClient](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.0/src/Symfony/Component/HttpClient/HttpClient.php) class to create the low-level HTTP client that makes requests, like the following GET request:

```
    use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient;

$client = HttpClient::create();
$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/symfony-docs');

$statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
// $statusCode = 200
$contentType = $response->getHeaders()['content-type'][0];
// $contentType = 'application/json'
$content = $response->getContent();
// $content = '{"id":521583, "name":"symfony-docs", ...}'
$content = $response->toArray();
// $content = ['id' => 521583, 'name' => 'symfony-docs', ...]
```

This is compatible with Symfony 5. Symfony Manual on this topic: [The HttpClient Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_client.html)