# How to put an external API into Symfony 2 project?

Tags: php, api, symfony

I am new here and hope to find help.

During my internship, I have to use an external API, coded in procedural PHP, into my Symfony2 project (version 2.7.13).
This API is a list with people names. When someone picks up his/her name, it will fill all the fields into a form (lastname, familyname, email, phone, department...).

The thing is that I understood that I have to put this API at the top of my form view, but I do not know how. 
I tried to do an include but it didn't work. Same result with a require_once. 
So I thought about declare it as a service and call it or put an absolute path to the API.

I think that you may find this question silly or beginner like, but I am alone on this project (and it is my first one without any teacher help), so your help is welcome.

Have a nice day,
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this could be helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072097/symfony2-how-to-perform-an-external-request

Comment: Thank you @vmagrez. I'm going to check it right away.