# Where to store access and refresh token from external web API in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, guzzle

I have created a simple Symfony2 project which allows employees to log in and check news and other stuff. Then I wanted to integrate an external system that shows whether the employee is at work or not. I have no control over the other system but I got an web API (REST) so that I may retrieve the information needed.

I decided to use [GuzzleBundle](https://github.com/8p/GuzzleBundle) as the PHP HTTP Client to get the information I need because of the answers in this [post (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072097/symfony2-how-to-perform-an-external-request).

So I logged in which is required by the web API:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$req = $client->request("POST", "https://httpbin.org/login",  ['body' => ['user' => 'user', 'pw' => 'pw']]);
$response = json_decode($req->getBody()->getContents());
```

And then I used the provided access token from $response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "content": [
    {
        "accessToken": "x",
        "accessTokenExpires": "date",
        "refreshToken": "z",
        "refreshTokenExpires": "date"
    }]
}
```

To retrieve information needed like this:

```
$reqPara     = ['body' =>["accessToken" => $at, "department" => $department, "location" =>$location]];

$req = $client->request("POST", "https://httpbin.org/employees/atwork", $reqPara);
$response = json_decode($req->getBody()->getContents());
```

And I got what I wanted:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "content": [
    {
        "employee": "a",
        "status": "at work",
    },
    {
        "employee": "b",
        "status": "not at work",
    }
    ]
}
```

And of course I can login each time I want to know if the employees is at work but that seems like a waste when I can use the access token. But then again when the access token expires I need the refresh token to generate new tokens **but where do I store these tokens and re-use them later? In a database or config file? Does it exist a standard for this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dmitry Malyshenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053255/dmitry-malyshenko) answered what I needed to hear. "It's obvious that this token must be cached, not stored in configuration. How it would be cached - it totally up to you..."

Examples of valid solutions:

- store in some file
- store in a database
- store just in memory (as a
  property of your class)
- store in some key-value storage (redis,
  memcache)

I would have used [CacheComponent](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html) but I am currently not developing in Symfony 3.1 so I decided to store in a database which felt most naturally. First I created a table with username, password and tokens in a mysql-database. Then I created a service dedicated to that table. It looks something like this simplified code:

```
class ExternalSiteService
{
    public function  getUsername() {
        ...
    }

    public function getPassword() {
        ...
    }

    public function getAccessToken() {
        ...
    }

    public function setAccessToken($newAccessToken) {
        ...
    }

    public function getRefreshToken() {
        $query="SELECT "
            . "eapi.refreshtoken "
            . "FROM external_api eapi";
        $connection = $this->em->getConnection();
        $statement = $connection->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();
        $results = $statement->fetchAll();
        if ( $results ) {
            return $results;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function setRefreshToken($newRefreshToken) {
        $query="UPDATE external_api "
            . "SET refreshtoken = :new_refreshtoken "
            . "WHERE id=1;";
        $connection = $this->em->getConnection();
        $statement = $connection->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue('new_refreshtoken', $newRefreshToken);
        $statement->execute();
    }
}
```

Then I made some logic in the controller that says if access token not valid use refresh token, and if refresh token not valid do a new login attempt. This code in the controller also stores the tokens in the database if we have to get new ones.

```
    $eapiService    = $this->get('mybundle.service.externalapi');
    $reqPara     = ['body' =>["accessToken" => $at, "department" => $department, "location" =>$location]];

    $req = $client->request("POST", "https://httpbin.org/employees/atwork", $reqPara);
    $response = json_decode($req->getBody()->getContents());

    if ($response->serverErrorMessage == "Invalid access token.") {
        $req = $client->request('POST', "https://httpbin.org/getnewtokens", ['body' => ['refreshToken' => $refreshToken]]);
        $response = json_decode($req->getBody()->getContents());

        if ($response->serverErrorMessage == "Invalid refresh token.") {
            $req = $client->request('POST', 'https://httpbin.org/login', ['body' => ['user' => $user, 'pw' => $pw]]);
            $response = json_decode($req->getBody()->getContents());
            foreach ($response->content as $contentItem) {
                $eapiService->setAccessToken($contentItem->accessToken);
                $eapiService->setRefreshToken($contentItem->refreshToken);
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($response->content as $contentItem) {
                $eapiService->setAccessToken($contentItem->accessToken);
                $eapiService->setRefreshToken($contentItem->refreshToken);
            }
        }
    }
    return array('usersatwork' => $response);
```

I will probably also make something to catch exceptions from guzzle.

Answer (score 1):

It's obvious that this token must be cached, not stored in configuration. How it would be cached - it totally up to you and normally depends on how often you start an application, how it configured when environment you have.

These all are valid solutions: to store in some file, to store in a database, to store just in memory (as a property of your class), to store in some key-value storage (redis, memcache).

If you use Symfony 3.1 I would recommend use [CacheComponent](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html) for this.

Answer (score -1):

Store your username and password inside the parameters.yml

Comment: Thanks B. I know of this optional configs in parameters.yml but if I save username and password does it mean that GuzzleBundle caches tokens? That I do not know. I may be wrong here but it seems "right" to use those tokens, e.g. a quick google search suggest higher safety when using the tokens.