# Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation and Tesco API

Tags: php, symfony, http

I am trying to recreate the following Tesco API code using Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation:

```
<?php
// This sample uses the Apache HTTP client from HTTP Components (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';

$request = new Http_Request2('https://dev.tescolabs.com/grocery/products/?query={query}&offset={offset}&limit={limit}');
$url = $request->getUrl();

$headers = array(
    // Request headers
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => '{subscription key}',
);

$request->setHeader($headers);

$parameters = array(
    // Request parameters
);

$url->setQueryVariables($parameters);

$request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);

// Request body
$request->setBody("{body}");

try
{
    $response = $request->send();
    echo $response->getBody();
}
catch (HttpException $ex)
{
    echo $ex;
}

?>
```

I am new to php in general and I am undertaking my first Symfony project. Could somebody please help me will recreating the above code using Symfony HttpFoundation instead?

I have tried the following code, and I return nothing:

```
        $req2 = Request::create('https://dev.tescolabs.com/grocery/products/?query={query}&offset={offset}&limit={limit}', 'GET');
        $req2->headers->set('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key', 'my_api_key');

        $params = array(
            'query' => 'walkers',
            'offset' => '0',
            'limit' => '10',
        );
        $req2->query->add($params);    

        try
        {
            $response = new Response();
            var_dump($response);die;
        }
        catch (HttpException $ex)
        {
            die ('EX: '.$ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony's `Request` class is used for an incoming request to Symfony. Maybe you should have a look at [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) to use an object-oriented approach to create a request or cURL like proposed in [Symfony2 - How to perform an external Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072097/symfony2-how-to-perform-an-external-request)

Comment: Thanks. Was very simple to do what I needed with Guzzle.